# How to use Gmail account to authenticate the app in android?

Tags: android

In android how can I authenticate the user by Gmail account. Is their any api or support available for android.

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use OAuth in Android. There's a fairly detailed post on this:

- [OAuth in Android using the Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/04/12/oauth-android-google-apis-client-library-java/)

There are also two other Java libraries that you might consider for this purpose:

- [Scribe Java API](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) (also supports using several other identity providers)
- [OAuth Signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/)

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking how to authenticate user in your android app?

You can create a gmail client to authenticate user based on their gmail a/c but This is a unsupported in android sdk.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10245999/350691
Hope it helps!