# Authentication with the gmail account - Android

Tags: android

I am developing an application that requires authentication, but I liked that authentication was done through the data from gmail, as is already used on many sites ..

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Cumpz

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551296/how-to-use-gmail-account-to-authenticate-the-app-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Take look at below link
http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/04/12/oauth-android-google-apis-client-library-java/