# with gmail login in android application

Tags: android

I am trying to develop such type of application .

In my android application log in with gmail .if gmail account not exist then as for signup.
and response in json formation .

i am search on google but not proper source code find .

please any one help me which api used for google login authentication.

Comment: use this to implement Google login in android app https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15300129/2065587) is the answer and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966831/using-google-account-to-log-in-on-android-application) is link to the related topic.

Comment: use google map api key