# I'm creating an Android App as a companion to the website, how should I authenticate?

Tags: android

I have a website where authentication is done through a web form.

I would like users of the app to be able to log in and register to the site from the app.

Will I have to create a RESTful webservice for the authentication and registration services?
Should I create an Oauth webservice?
Or is there a simpler way I have overlooked?
Also would it be possible to log in is only done once to persist the lifetime of the app, unless user clicks log out?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way....

1. Create your authentication by simple email password verification.
2. post your parameters on a giver url.
3. If email password authenticates...give user a unique id in response.
4. Store that unique id in shared preferences.
5. check that shared preferences every time user opens his application.
6. And when user log out clear the shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from user perspective I would highly suggest login using existing Google account. There is [Using google-account to log in on Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966831/using-google-account-to-log-in-on-android-application) discussion. Almost every android phone have at least one Google account logged in ( for play market)